# Magento 1.5x add a new category programmatically and return category ID

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering how to create new categories programmatically in magento 1.5xx. Also I need to return the category ID back once its been created.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an initial post here which was completely wrong - it's not as easy to find the answer to this on Google as it should be!

Anyway, here's some code I'm using in Magento 1.5.0.1

```
-- The parent category you want to work with.
$parentCategory = $this->getParentCategory(); 
-- This method needs to refer to the static block you want to display if you're using one.
$categoryBlockId = $this->getCategoryBlockId(); 

$category = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' );
$category->setStoreId( $storeId );
$category->setName( $categoryName ); -- The name of the category
$category->setUrlKey( $categoryUrlkey ); -- The category's URL identifier
$category->setIsActive( 1 ); -- Is it enabled?
$category->setIsAnchor( 0 ); -- I think this relates to whether it shows in navigation.
-- Display mode can be 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE', 'PAGE', or (I think) 'PRODUCTS'
$category->setDisplayMode( $displayMode ); 
$category->setPath( $parentCategory->getPath() ); -- Important you get this right.
-- This is required if DisplayMode is 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE' or 'PAGE'.
$category->setLandingPage( $categoryBlockId ); 
$category->setPageTitle( 'Your Page Title' );
$category->save()

$categoryId = $category->getId();
```

There are other properties you can use as well (they correlate to the form fields when adding a category in the admin panel) but I don't have examples for them unfortunately. There are good posts out there online - I used them to create the above - but you might need to dig deeply via Google to find them.

I hope this helps and that you didn't read my first answer which wouldn't help.

Cheers,
Zac